# Is it ok to lubricate exercise equipment hydraulic cylinders?

Tags: repair, appliances, lubrication

I have a Pro-Form 220c Hydraulic Cylinder based stepper.  After about 10 minutes of use the right cylinder stops offering any resistance.  I suspect that it's related to it getting hotter.

With normal usage they are supposed to get hot, so this isn't unexpected. I don't feel a noticeable difference between the two cylinders.  A new one costs about $60, but before I do that, I was wondering if it was possible to lubricate it?

If so, with what?

Comment: Ask the manufacturer.The question will probably be which lubricants are safe for the seals on those cylinders, and only the manufacturer is likely to know that. They may also have a more accurate answer for why that cylinder is giving you trouble, and possibly a simple adjustment which will be a better fix than lube.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace it. There is nothing to "lubricate" (it's already full of oil) and if there was it would not **increase** resistance.  You have some sort of failure in the valving/orifices that restrict the flow of the oil inside the cylinder and convert motion to heat.

They are more directly analogous to shock absorbers (as on your car) than "hydraulic cylinders" and the vast majority of shock absorbers are not rebuildable, including the ones used on most exercise equipment.